# Views not visible on Nokia 8.1

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, nokia

The screen shows a map, a bottom tab bar and some buttons on the map. The map is shown inside a SupportMapFragment using google maps.

I use the following dependencies for the google libs:

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0"
implementation "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.6.2"
```

As well as version 2.0.1 for the constraint layout.

The layout xml can be found here: https://gist.github.com/CordulaAndune/c874c139ef72bb95b724149b7ee9dd72

This is working correctly on all devices except Nokia 8.1 with Android 10. Here only the map is shown, all other views are not visible, which makes the app unusable. It seems like the problem can sometimes be solved by reinstalling or updating the app.

[Screenshot of the broken app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axgiu.png)

I found this issue on the google issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149937393. But since the bottom tab bar is also affected, the elevation cannot be the problem.

I did not find any hints in the implementation why this occurs.

Any suggestions what the problem could be on that Nokia device?

Comment: I think there is a problem with nokia itself https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/32169/navigation-bar-issue

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I don't see how this relates to my issue